# When i run the website in the local i have no console errors but after upload it i see this error

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

This is the Error i have in the Console
a1vocaless.html:119 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at a1vocaless.html:119:1156)
This 119 is the closing body tag.
here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Nur-Deutch home page</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row m-2">
      <div id="log" class="col-8">
        <a href="index.html">
          <div><img src="log3.png" alt="" /></div
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            id="x"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Courses
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="x">
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="a1index.html">A1 - Beginner</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="a2index.html">A2 - Elementary</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="b1index.html">B1 - Intermediate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="b2index.html"
                >B2 - Upper Intermediate</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col"><div class="btn btn-outline-danger">Blog</div></div>
      <div class="col"><div class="btn btn-outline-dark">About me</div></div>
      <div class="col"><div class="btn btn-outline-dark">Contact</div></div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide -->
    
      <div class="row all">
        <div class ="col-3">
          <ul id="titles">
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(45)" href="#">Die Stellung des Verbs in Aussagesätzen, W-Fragen und Ja-/Nein-Fragen </a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(46)" href="#">Konjugation im Präsens Singular und Höflichkeitsform von kommen, heißen, sprechen, sein</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(47)" href="#">Possessivartikel mein, meine</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(48)" href="#">Pesonalpronomen: sie, Sie und sie (Pl.)</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(49)" href="#">Erweiterte Konjugation im Präsens von haben, wohnen, leben, sein</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(50)" href="#">Der bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel im Singular</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(51)" href="#">Verneinung mit nicht und kein/keine</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(52)" href="#">Ja-/Nein-Fragen und W-Fragen mit Was?</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(53)" href="#">Wortbildung Komposita</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(54)" href="#">Vollständige Konjugation im Präsens von sein, machen, sprechen, lesen</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(55)" href="#">Artikel im Nominativ und Akkusativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(56)" href="#">Ja-/Nein-Fragen und W-Fragen mit Wie viel?</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(57)" href="#">Nomen im Plural</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(58)" href="#">Die Verben brauchen, kaufen, essen, mögen im Präsens</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(59)" href="#">Die Stellung der temporalen Adverbien immer, oft, manchmal, nie im Satz</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(60)" href="#">Trennbare Verben anrufen, einkaufen, aufstehen, fernsehen</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(61)" href="#">Personalpronomen in der 3. Person Singular und Plural</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(62)" href="#">Die Possessivartikel mein(-e), dein(-e), ihr(-e), Ihr(-e)</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(63)" href="#">Der Imperativ (Sie)</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(64)" href="#">Die Verben fahren, nehmen, gehen im Präsens</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(65)" href="#">Die Präpositionen mit Dativ: mit, an, zu, bei, in</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(66)" href="#">Lokale Präpositionen</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(67)" href="#">Die Modalverben können und müssen im Präsens und ihre Stellung im Satz</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(68)" href="#">Das trennbare Verb anfangen im Präsens</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(69)" href="#">Possessivartikel im Nominativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(70)" href="#">Die Modalverben sollen und dürfen</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(71)" href="#">Der Imperativ ( ihr und du)</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(72)" href="#">Das Perfekt mit haben und sein</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(73)" href="#">Das Partizip II</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(74)" href="#">Die Verbstellung im Perfekt</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(75)" href="#">Das Präteritum von sein und haben</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(76)" href="#">Unbestimmter Artikel im Dativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(77)" href="#">Personalpronomen im Dativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(78)" href="#">Der Komparativ und Superlativ von Adjektiven</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(79)" href="#">Welcher und dieser im Nominativ und Akkusativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(80)" href="#">Verben mit Akkusativ und Verben mit Dativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(81)" href="#">Das Modalverb wollen</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(82)" href="#">Wortbildung Komposita</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(83)" href="#">Temporale Präpositionen mit Dativ</a></li>
            <li><a class="ttl" onclick="showContent(84)" href="#">Die Ordinalzahlen</a></li>
            
 

          </ul> 
        </div> 
        <div class ="col-6">
        <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
         
         
      </div>
    
    <!-- slide -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know why i have this error in the console only when the website online, i mean when i run it in my coputer its works fine and without any errors.

Comment: There is a `main.js` in the bottom, what does it do? Does that script execute correctly, because it looks like you don't wait for jQuery / Bootstrap to be loaded.

Comment: Sorry i'm new be so what should i do?

Comment: You should include the contents of the main.js file in this question. Or you should test your html page without the javascript files, and see if you still get an error. Another thing you can try is to only execute `main.js` after all other javascript has loaded. You could load it as the last script (after jquery and bootstrap) and add the `defer` keyword: `<script defer src="main.js">`. But this is just a guess, since we don't know your JS code.